# flex item width is always equal to intrinsic width of image content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Goal**

1. I want to set an image inside a div(child) which is a flex item inside a flex container div(parent).
2. I want the image to have height equal to its containing div(child) while still maintaining it's aspect ratio.

**My understanding**

1. If I set the height of the image to 100% then the image will change its size to match the containing div(child) height while still maintaining its aspect ratio.**(this works as expected)**
2. The width of the containing div(child) will be equal to the new width of the image after it has been scaled to match its container height.**(this doesn't work as expected)**

**Problem**

The width of the container div(child) is equal to the intrinsic width of the image rather than the new width of the scaled-down image, leaving additional space on right of the container div(child).

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .parent {
             display: flex;
             width: 1000px;
             height: 400px;
             padding: 10px 0px;
             background-color: red;
         }
         .child {
             padding: 10px 0px;
             background-color: blue;
         }
         .child > img {
             height: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg" alt="some img">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach or not but I ended up solving this by adding `height: 100%;` to `.child` as well as to `.child > img`. Here is the final code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .parent {
             display: flex;
             width: 1000px;
             height: 400px;
             padding: 10px 0px;
             background-color: red;
         }
         .child {
             height: 100%;
             background-color: blue;
         }
         .child > img {
             height: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg" alt="some img">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .parent {
             display: flex;
             width: 1000px;
             height: 400px;
             padding: 10px 0px;
             background-color: red;
         }
         .child {
             padding: 10px 0px;
             background-color: blue;
         }
         .child > img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
         }
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="parent">
         <div class="child">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg" alt="some img">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I set both height and width to 100% then it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of image to 100% so it will take whole div. And for image to not lose its pixel you can add  `object-fit:cover;`
Here is the working example
https://codepen.io/maha986/pen/BaWqrGb

And if you want to decrease the size of the child div then you can set it's width to whatever you want

You can have your child and image styling like this

```
         .child {

             padding: 10px 0px;
           width:500px;

             background-color: blue;

         }

         .child > img {

             height: 100%;
width:100%;

         }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if i set both width and height to 100% then it loses it's aspect ratio.